I’m encountering difficulties installing ETAP on my Mac using Wine. The installation process fails when attempting to set up the SQL Local DB server
I need to run ETAP on my Mac for college, but since there’s no native Mac version, I tried using Whisky (Wine) for the installation. The setup process goes smoothly until the very end, where I encounter an error message stating:

"Unable to install Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Local DB. Installation error code 29559."

As I'm new to using Wine/CrossOver, I may have overlooked some important details.
